# Python struct.pack() data range error

Tags: python-2.7, struct.pack

I'm using python2.7 and I have this code. Data values are range from 0 to 65792.

```
data_length=30
code=202
data=[51400,31400,100,51400,31400,100,51400,31400,100]
checksum = 0
total_data = ['$', 'M', '<', data_length, code] + data
for i in struct.pack('<2B%dh' % len(data), *total_data[3:len(total_data)]):
    checksum = checksum ^ ord(i)
total_data.append(checksum)
try:
    b = None
    b = self.ser.write(struct.pack('<3c2B%dhB' % len(data), *total_data))
except Exception, error:
    print "\n\nError in sendCMD."
    print "("+str(error)+")\n\n"
    pass

struct.pack('<2B%dh' % len(data), *total_data[3:len(total_data)]):
```

and gives me this error:

```
for i in struct.pack('<2B%dh' % len(data), *total_data[3:len(total_data)]):
struct.error: short format requires SHRT_MIN <= number <= SHRT_MAX
```

Comment: `h` is a signed short and its maximum positive value is 32768. `H` is an unsigned short and its max is 65535. Neither fit your max.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SHRT_MAX` is defined as 0x7FFF (32767) as shorts are signed: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/limits.h

Perhaps you want unsigned short? `H` in `struct.pack`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters

EDIT: even then, A value at your maximum range (65792) will overflow unsigned short -- you'll need a larger container such as int (`i`) or unsigned int (`I`) to work with those values

Comment: Alas, even unsigned short is too small for 65792.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney :D, noticed that right after I pressed post